# Множественный выбор в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Здраствуйте. в общем, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно сделать множественный выбор элементов в списке. Но по непонятным, мне причинам, при нажатии например на первый элемент, почему-то где-то в середине или конце,так же применяется клик, и меняется фон элемента там,где я не прожимал ничего. Отзеркаливание будто какое-то. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
Вот собственно код:

```
public class MultipleClickAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MultipleClickAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public MultipleClickAdapter(List<TestList> testLists, Context context) {
    this.testLists = testLists;
    this.context = context;
}


private List<TestList> testLists;
private Context context;



@NonNull
@NotNull
@Override
public MultipleClickAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_test, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull MultipleClickAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    final TestList list = testLists.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(list.getS());
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.setActive(!list.isActive());
            holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(list.isActive() ? Color.CYAN : Color.RED);
            

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return testLists.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView textView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_test);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTest);

    }
}}
```

Активити

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MultipleClickAdapter mAdapter;
;
   private ArrayList<TestList> lists = new ArrayList<>();
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.testrecycler);
       lists = new ArrayList<>();


       for (int i = 0;i<35;++i)
       {
           lists.add(new TestList(i+""));
       }

       mAdapter = new MultipleClickAdapter(lists,getApplicationContext());
       LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(TestActivity.this);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


   }
}
```

Айтем

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linear_test"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:background="#545665"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="45dp">
       <TextView
           android:text="click me"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/textTest"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textAllCaps="true"
           android:textColor="#FFF"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Обьект

Обьект класс

````
public class TestList {


    private String s;
    private boolean isActive;


    public TestList(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }



    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы вам предложил добавить в адаптер поле с массивом выбранных позиций, куда складывать все что вы понажимали. Дальше вы при скролле просто проверяйте если позиция есть в массиве, то сетите цвет выбранного элемента, в противном случае цвет не выбранного. Так же можно добавить кеширование:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

где 20 это число элементов которые вы хотите кешировать.

Comment: Спасибо.Вроде как помогает в моем случае